# Eclipse Debugging with Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but when I setup my Nexus to debug with eclipse I get a error in the console saying

> [2011-12-27 21:48:31 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring 0146BF5417006010

Then I run `adb` devices through Android platform-tools/adb.exe and my device shows up as "offline".

I have tried the following:

1. removed all drivers, re installed with device disconnected.
2. USB debugging is on.
3. re installed drives while device is connected
4. rolled back drivers in device manager.

on a side note I did have this working previously with my Droid and Droid 3

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is OS version on nexus supported version for your app?

Comment: my app is 2.2, nexus has 4.0.2. however that shouldn't affect the adb devices manager from showing it as offline right?

Comment: Did you try by restarting machine. It seems most probably reasons are (couple of google searches): 1) Not compatble driver 2) Cable is not good

Comment: yea, I've tried restarting between each step, I have also tried 2 separate cables however neither is the particular cable that shipped with the device. They allow me to view files on the device and such but could that be an issue?

Comment: It could be if the cable is not supported.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that a Motorola Droid 3 cable would not work. But I will try and locate the original cable. In the mean time are there any other suggestions?

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is completly uninstall drivers related to nexus and re-install them. One of these should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that my path was not set correctly on my system.

thanks for the answers though.

Comment: What part of the path was missing?

Comment: Bummer we don't have more info here.  I'm having the same issue and have no idea what path kds is referring to.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same Problem. 
2 Ways worked for me:

1. Way: 
   Download the USB-drivers from http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW
   But be carefull. For me only the drivers in US English worked.
2. Way:
   Go to the device manager Computer -> righ click -> properties -> device manager. There you should manage to find a samsung device. 
   Go to poperties -> drivers -> update drivers -> browse my computer for driver software.
   Then select android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver

And:
Be sure to run Eclipse as Admin. With restricted user rights you can not connect the ADB from Eclipse.

Comment: "For me only the drivers in US English worked." That's exactly what did the trick for me. Had previously installed the German drivers which would not work. Thanks.